# What is the algorithm to count the number of 1 bits in a 64-bit integer?

Tags: c, binary, hex, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

For example:

./bit_count 0x123456789abcdef0
bit_count(0x123456789abcdef0) returned 32

What would be an algorithm to count the number of 1-bits in the 64-bit integer value that was passed in to the given function above.

Any help would be much appreciated?

Comment: There's also [this handy cheatsheet](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) from Stanford which might have better answers than the dupe target.

Answer (score 1):

One of approaches is the following

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t bit_count( uint64_t n )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for (; n != 0; n &= n - 1)
    {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%zu\n", bit_count( 0x123456789abcdef0 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
32
```

Comment: This algorithm is credited to Brian Kernighan (the K of K&R) but might have been invented before that. This (and lots more) [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan).